# webRTC - stream webcam in real time on a webpage

Tags: node.js, websocket, video-streaming, webrtc, webcam

I need to stream online in real time the video captured from my domestic webcam
making it appearing in a webpage accessible from anywhere,
so I can watch it from a browser by entering something like `http://example.com/webcamStream`

I readed some stuff about websockets and webRTC, and seems that in my case the best option could be webRTC

I already installed a webserver (apache) and set my domestic router that now redirects external requests to the apache server

I installed node.js, node_modules socket.io, express, ws

I did some little tests following some tutorials like [this one](http://www.programwitherik.com/socket-io-tutorial-with-node-js-and-express) (that creates a little websocket chat)

and [this one](https://shanetully.com/2014/09/a-dead-simple-webrtc-example/) that creates a video stream using webRTC

in the second example I was able to start the video stream but I am still confused about how to make that stream accessible from thw web, it is still not definitely clear to me as I am not very experienced with these kind of things

I hope someone can help me to understand what I need in order to accomplish that webcam stream from my house, any help will be really appreciated :)

Comment: [this](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/one-to-many-video-broadcasting) might be what you are looking for, but as the amount of viewers increase, it is going to be a problem...

Comment: @mido22 what you mean exactly? I am not sure what you mean with _"the amount of viewers increase"_